# The union of finitely many closed sets is closed

Tags: general-topology

I understand how the definitions unpack for this proof, but I'm not sure how to formally word it.

Let $(X, \tau$) be a topological space. We say that $A \subseteq X$ is *closed* if $X\setminus A \in \tau$. If $I$ is a ﬁnite index set and for each $i \in I$, $A_{i}$ is closed, then $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}A_{i}$ is closed.

Comment: De Morgan's laws and definition of topology would help.

Comment: There is no single way to formally word a proof.  Different people have different styles.  The only feature your formal proof should contain is a clear logical flow from one idea to the next.  When I'm writing proofs for homework problems (or even when just proving things for myself), I typically write my explanation for each step in words, rather than expecting the reader to know why I jumped from one step to the next.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}=\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}^{c}\right)^{c}$
where $B^{c}$ stands for the complement of any $B\subseteq X$ in
$X$.

Notice that the $A_{i}^{c}$ are open (i.e. are elements of
$\tau$) as complements of the closed $A_{i}$.

If $I$ is finite then $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_{i}^{c}$
is a finite intersection of open sets hence is open (a characteristic
of a topology).

Its complement (which is $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_{i}$) is then a closed
set.

Answer (score 0):

If $A_i$ is a finite family of closed sets then $X\setminus A_i$ is open for each $i$ and so
$\bigcap X\setminus A_i$ is open (as open sets are closed under finite intersection). Hence $X\setminus (\bigcap X\setminus A_i) = \bigcup A_i$  is open.

Answer (score 0):

By calling $I$ a finite index set, we just mean we have finitely many closed sets $A_{i}$.

We need to show $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i}$ is closed if we know that for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, $A_{i}$ is closed.  But, as you stated, a set is closed if its complement is in the topology $\tau$.  So, to show $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i}$ is closed, we need to show $X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} \in \tau$.

But, by DeMorgan's laws, $X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} = \bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{n} X \setminus A_{i}$.  Now, for each $i$, we said $A_{i}$ is closed, which means $X \setminus A_{i} \in \tau$.  Since $\tau$ is a topology, it is closed under finite intersections.  So, since each of the $X \setminus A_{i}$'s is in $\tau$, and there are only finitely many of them, we know $\bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{n} X \setminus A_{i} \in \tau$ (again, this is because for any *finite* set of things in $\tau$, their intersection is in $\tau$, too).

So we just showed $\bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{n} X \setminus A_{i} \in \tau$.  But we said by DeMorgan's laws that $X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} = \bigcap \limits_{i = 1}^{n} X \setminus A_{i}$, and so this means $X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} \in \tau$.

Finally, since $X \setminus \bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i} \in \tau$, by your definition of closed, that means $\bigcup \limits_{i = 1}^{n} A_{i}$ is closed.